# How to center relative layout with its text and images?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-relativelayout, centering

I have `RelativeLayout` which has other elements such as imageview, textview inside it. When i run the app with small screen size (Galaxy S2) it is displayed as image 1. But when it runs on a larger screen (Nexus 7) it is displayed as in image 2. I do not want to enlarge the image for larger screens and i want it to keep certain sizes i set (see .xml). But how i can make it appears at the center on large screens (as in image 3).

[image: Small screen] [image: Large Screen] [image: Desired one]

Thank you for suggestions.

**.xml file:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ll1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/stainbck"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="25dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Customized Templates"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#eaeaea" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn7"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn8"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="8" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="265dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:longClickable="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/blankcard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crdCompany"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Company"
        android:textColor="#20526d"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crdWebsite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="website"
        android:textColor="#20526d"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crdAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/crdPhone"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="address"
        android:textColor="#20526d"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crdEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/crdWebsite"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/crdWebsite"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="email"
        android:textColor="#20526d"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crdPhone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/crdWebsite"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:text="phone"
        android:textColor="#20526d"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crdName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/crdCompany"
        android:text="name"
        android:textColor="#20526d"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crdTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/crdName"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="title"
        android:textColor="#20526d"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crdMobile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/crdTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="mobile"
        android:textColor="#20526d"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/crdlogoframe"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/border"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/crdqrframe"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/border" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomrltv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnsend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Send" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnedit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnsend"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Edit" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Note:** .xml file demonstrates whole interface, not only RelativeLayout.

Comment: use weight for this and make diffrent2 values folder for that

Comment: @rashi. Can you pls demonstrate in answer that i have chance to accept it as an answer and vote. thx.

Comment: if you use main parent view as relative layout after use android:centerInParent='true' so that will work..please try it..but you want to manage below and above view in relative view if you use this..

Comment: i place android:layout_centerInParent="true" into imageView and later also inti relativeLayout but it doesnt work unfortunately.

Comment: @Umitk just make values folder and in values folder provide style.xml for diffrent2 size..so you will get that

Comment: I am not familiar with it. Can you provide me demonstration pls. Then i can tick it as my answer as well. thx

Comment: ok @rashi. since this question is not answered yet, i ll be waiting for your answer. thx

Comment: @Umitk i will sure give u answer..dnt wory..r8 now i have ofc work stuck soo much..

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you need to center imageview with id blankcard inside his parent relativelayout? Then you can set android:centerInParent='true'...

Comment: this didnt work. but i want to emphasize for u that this relative layout also has textviews rather than imageview only. thats why i dont think setting imageview center will solve this alone. though i tried. but didnt work. thx